# jQuery EditForm redirect to DispForm

Tags: jquery, redirect, edit-form, display-form

I want to redirect user after editing item and pressing save button to item `DispForm`. I currently have JS code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('input[value=Save]').click(function() {
                var ur = window.location.assign;
                var URL = ur.replace('EditForm.aspx','DispForm.aspx');
                window.location.assign(URL);  
            });
        });
```

Problem with this code currently is, that it works time to time.. Which means, it does redirect to `DispForm` few times and then JS seems to fail load and redirect to default `AllItems`.

Comment: me too facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

You want to override `function PreSaveAction()` instead of detecting the click with JQuery.

Comment: You should override `PreSaveItem`, not `PreSaveAction`.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint instead of $(document).ready you should use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`
for you this would look like this:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");
function myCustomFunctionName(){
            $('input[value=Save]').click(function() {
                var ur = window.location.assign;
                var URL = ur.replace('EditForm.aspx','DispForm.aspx');
                window.location.assign(URL);  
            });

}
```

Reference Link:       http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work, I managed to get it redirect me back to `DispForm` only one time in about 10 tries. Also reading the link, then `$` should be replaced with `jQuery`?

Comment: I guess it happens because the "Save" Button is controlled server side and not on client side. It would be better if you would just edit your Form or create a new one manually and create the behaviour you want. It's easy if you use InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps easier way, to redirect to a specific page after submission is to add the Source querystring parameter to the current page URL, like this:

```
http://yoursite/path-to-your-edit-form.aspx?ID=someid&Source=/yoursite/path-to-your-display-form.aspx?ID=someid
```

Comment: how to add source querystring parameter in the URL ?, programmatically

Answer (score 0):

As said before... Overwrite the presaveaction() and put something like this in:

```
newURL = "DispForm.aspx?ID=" + YOUR_FORM_ID_HERE
currentURL = $("form")[0].action;
postbackURL = currentURL.replace(GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, currentURL), newURL);
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions($('[name$="$diidIOSaveItem"]').attr('name'), "", true, "", postbackURL, false, true));
```

Havent tested it. You just need to grab the ID of the current Item, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the parameter of the form:

```
var URL = location.href.replace('EditForm.aspx', 'DispForm.aspx');
URL = URL.substring(0, URL.indexOf("&"));
$('form').attr('action', "EditForm.aspx?ID=" + GetUrlKeyValue("ID") + "&Source=" + escapeProperly(URL));
```

The save button only calls a JS function which takes the form parameters.